# Does Anyone Know How To Implement CHAINLINK AUTOAMTION (Keepers) To be the "Executor" of the "Timelock" contract in a DAO?

Tags: chainlink, foundry, dao, timelock, chainlink-automation

I am trying to add a different element to a DAO - and that is to make Chainlink be the automatic "executor" of the "timelock" contract when the minDelay amount of time has passed. I have been tryig for days, but i cannot figure out how to implement it. Does anyone know how it can be done?

```
contract TimeLock is AutomationCompatibleInterface, TimelockController {
// minDelay is how long ou have to wait before executing
// proposers is the list of addresses that can propose
// executors is the list of addresses taht can execute
// admin
constructor(
    uint256 minDelay,
    address[] memory proposers,
    address[] memory executors
) TimelockController(minDelay, proposers, executors, msg.sender) {}
```

that is the normal TimeLock contract that is used and it inherits fucntionality from openzeppelin TimeLockController contracts.

when the governor passes a vot, it proposes it to be queued to the timelock so that a certain amount of time passes before the vote gets implemented. The Executor of the timelock is left open so anyone can execute the change to the dao after the minDelay time passes. I am trying to make Chainlink Autoamtion (Keepers) be the executor and add autoamtion to the DAO. I am also using Foundry's Forge

Answer (score 0):

To create an upkeep-compatible contract check out the documentation at https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-automation/guides/compatible-contracts

It sounds like you would need to create a checkUpkeep function that is looking for a `TimeLock` value. If it has passed, then for that proposal, you would want to return true.

`performUpkeep` would need to only execute on proposals that haven't been executed and are passed their `timeLock`

something like

```
    struct Proposal {
        uint256 timeLock;
        uint proposalId;
    }

    Proposal[] public proposals;
```